# DO WHILE loop with OpenMP in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, do-while

I am creating a random distribution of points in Fortran, and this is being done by a do while loop. I want to speed up this process via OpenMP, but I read that you can't simply use !$OMP PARALLEL DO for do while loops. I tried converting my original do while into a do loop nested in the do while. However, I can't see any speedups in the code,by this I mean it takes the same time as the serial version. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is and I've been stuck, would appreciate any advice. I've shown the code below.

The original loop:

```
!OMP PARALLEL DO
do while (count < size(zeta_list,2))
    call random_number(x)
    call random_number(y)
    x1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*x)
    y1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*y)
    if (abs(y1) <= abs(1/x1)) then
        count = count + 1
        call random_number(theta)
        zeta_list(1,count) = x1*sin(2*pi_16*theta)
        zeta_list(2,count) = x1*cos(2*pi_16*theta)
    end if 
end do  
!OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

and after I tried to convert it,

```
!$OMP PARALLEL 
do while (count < size(zeta_list,2))
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,size(zeta_list,2),1
        call random_number(x)
        call random_number(y)
        x1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*x)
        y1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*y)
        if (abs(y1) <= abs(1/x1)) then
            call random_number(theta)
            count = count + 1
            zeta_list(1,i) = x1*sin(2*pi_16*theta)
            zeta_list(2,i) = x1*cos(2*pi_16*theta)
        end if
    end do
    !$OMP END DO 
end do  
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

The entire code is

```
PROGRAM RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION

IMPLICIT NONE 

DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(2,1000000)::zeta_list
DOUBLE PRECISION::x,y,x1,y1,theta
REAL::a,b,n
INTEGER::count,t1,t2,clock_rate,clock_max,i
DOUBLE PRECISION,PARAMETER::pi_16=4*atan(1.0_16)

call system_clock ( t1, clock_rate, clock_max )

n = 1000
b = n/2
a = -n/2
count = 0
zeta_list = 0
x = 0
y = 0
x1 = 0 
y1 = 0 
theta = 0

call random_seed()



!$OMP PARALLEL 
do while (count < size(zeta_list,2))
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,size(zeta_list,2),1
        call random_number(x)
        call random_number(y)
        x1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*x)
        y1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*y)
        if (abs(y1) <= abs(1/x1)) then
            call random_number(theta)
            count = count + 1
            zeta_list(1,i) = x1*sin(2*pi_16*theta)
            zeta_list(2,i) = x1*cos(2*pi_16*theta)
        end if
    end do
    !$OMP END DO 
end do  
!$OMP END PARALLEL


call system_clock ( t2, clock_rate, clock_max )
write ( *, * ) 'Elapsed real time = ', real ( t2 - t1 ) / real ( clock_rate) ,'seconds' 


stop
END PROGRAM RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION
```

compiled with gfortran test.f90 -fopenmp

Comment: How do you measure the speedup? Shiw the actual results. How large is the unshown part of the code (se [mcve])? How are your variables declared?

Comment: Which compilers do you use? Not all compilers allow `random_number` in parallel and some may generate the numbers in serial even if they allow `random_number` in parallel. There are parallel random number generators available.

Comment: There is much to say about your sample. 1. the result will depend on the size of `zeta_list` in its second dimension. If it is small, the cost of threading will make any speedup unlikely. 2. Using OpenMP without declaring the "thread bound" variable makes your results wrong and your code slow. 3. As Vladimir mentions, random number in parallel are *not* an obvious thing to do. 4. There is an innocent looking `_16` underscore on your pi variable. What is your "typing" plan?

Comment: This is no answer yet but in short: start OpenMP with a simpler example, use tests to check that your results are valid after OpenMP-ing, document yourself about the random number feature in parallel. This *is* compiler-dependent so you might want to pick a fixed compiler for your code or use a library that provides thread-safe random number generation.

Comment: I see, I should check up on thread-safe rngs. I measure speedup using wall clock times, and the rest of the code is very small, let me re-edit my initial post to show the whole thing. I've been using gfortran to compile, but I also have ifort ( haven't tried on it ). I tried with large zeta_list sizes to cover up the cost of threading, and I've used openmp before, am just confused about the logic for a do while loop and its variable declarations.

Comment: Well, right now you have a race condition in `count`. Multiple threads may be reading it and writing it at the same time. And one of those readings is in the condition of the `do while` loop. You will need some `private`, `shared` maybe `reduction` and so on...

Comment: On count, x, y, x1, y1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of performing a hard-to distribute while loop, I propose the following: use a loop over the array index.

I suppose that you want to generate random samples in the array `zeta_list`. I moved the while in the parallel loop.

Still, beware that you need a "OpenMP-aware" PRNG. This is the case in recent gfortran versions, I don't know for other compilers.

I also changed the 1.0_16 into a a `1.0d0` as fixed numeric constants are not a good way to specify the kind parameter in general and reduced the size of the static array.

```
PROGRAM RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION

  IMPLICIT NONE 

  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(2,100000)::zeta_list
  DOUBLE PRECISION::x,y,x1,y1,theta
  REAL::a,b,n
  INTEGER::count,t1,t2,clock_rate,clock_max,i
  DOUBLE PRECISION,PARAMETER::pi_16=4*atan(1.0d0)

  call system_clock ( t1, clock_rate, clock_max )

  n = 1000
  b = n/2
  a = -n/2
  count = 0
  zeta_list = 0
  x = 0
  y = 0
  x1 = 0 
  y1 = 0 
  theta = 0

  call random_seed()

  !$OMP PARALLEL DO private(i, x, y, x1, y1, theta)
  do i = 1, size(zeta_list, 2)
     inner_loop: do
        call random_number(x)
        call random_number(y)
        x1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*x)
        y1 = a + FLOOR((b+1-a)*y)
        if (abs(y1) <= abs(1/x1)) then
           call random_number(theta)
           zeta_list(1,i) = x1*sin(2*pi_16*theta)
           zeta_list(2,i) = x1*cos(2*pi_16*theta)
           exit inner_loop
        end if
     end do inner_loop
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

  write(*,*) zeta_list(:,1)
  write(*,*) zeta_list(:,2)

  call system_clock ( t2, clock_rate, clock_max )
  write ( *, * ) 'Elapsed real time = ', real ( t2 - t1 ) / real ( clock_rate) ,'seconds' 

END PROGRAM RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION
```

The use of `random_number` in OpenMP threads is safe for gfortran 5 but you need gfortran 7 to get a *threaded* random number generator. I list the timing with two cores:

```
user@pc$ gfortran-5 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -o prd prd.f90
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./prd
   47.496326386583306        237.29327630545950     
  -101.11803913888293        147.70288474064185     
 Elapsed real time =    3.47700000     seconds
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./prd
   0.0000000000000000       -0.0000000000000000     
  -160.53394672041205        49.526275353269853     
 Elapsed real time =    12.1479998     seconds
user@pc$ rm fort.1*
user@pc$ gfortran-5 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -o prd prd.f90
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =    3.05100012     seconds
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =    9.09599972     seconds
user@pc$ gfortran-6 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -o prd prd.f90
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =    3.09200001     seconds
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =    12.3350000     seconds
user@pc$ gfortran-7 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -o prd prd.f90
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =    1.83200002     seconds
user@pc$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./prd
 Elapsed real time =   0.986999989     seconds
```

The result is quite obvious: prior to gfortran 7 OpenMP-ing the code here slows it down significantly.

Comment: @francescalus yes

Comment: I tried this for a zeta_list with (2,1e6), with 4 omp threads and compared with the serial, seems to be much slower. Serial : 24.9 seconds , 4 Threads : 115.7 seconds. I tried with 1e7 as well to make sure the overhead wasn't the issue. seems like its not. My Gfortran version is 5.4. Is this version too old?

Comment: @ThunderFlash I don't know if you receive notifications for edits. I added timings and you need gfortran >= 7

Comment: @PierredeBuyl yeah you don't get notifs for edits. Ah let me check this then, thanks !

Comment: Is a like "USE OMP" required?

Comment: `use omp` is only required for call to OpenMP runtime functions, like `omp_get_thread_num`, etc.